# Access specific URL in my app service when using Azure AD Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

We are currently having problem allowing a user to a specific URL without logging in in Azure AD authentication.

We are successful in getting token and using it for our API's. But we are currently having problem allowing user to access a URL without them logging in.

What we have tried so far was this links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your second link, in the azure portal-> your app service -> authentication and authorization screen, make sure the "action to take when request is not authenticated" is set to allow anonymous. if you set that option to "log in with active directory" that forces authentication on every page no matter what. And ensure in your code that page doesn't require login eg.remove the [authorize] tag.